# How do I deserialize a struct through its own `new` constructor?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I wish to deserialize the below struct, but using the `new` constructor to validate the deserialized fields:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Timestamp {
    values: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Timestamp {
    pub fn new(values: Vec<u32>) -> Timestamp {
        // some quality check
        Timestamp { values: values }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do that? I looked into writing a custom `Deserializer`, but I hoped that there would be an easier and less verbose way to do that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach wow, usually I don't miss key things like that. Thanks!

Comment: The [duplicate applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f59c0bcd780fff3b5b4fa161eb348f0).